# Source of figure below caption is not centered when there are too many characters

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I want my figure source to be part of the caption but in an new line, everything located below the figure and both of the lines should be centered. 
This works out perfectly as long as the caption (1st line) is not too long. Obviously both lines are automatically aligned to the left side when there are too many characters in the caption.
How can I prevent this behaviour?

That's what it should look like:

```
[Picture] (--> centered)
Figure 2.2: blablabla (--> centered)
Source: blabla (--> centered)
```

I have tried it with: 
\caption*{...} in a new line but the result is not satisfying, because then there is too much space between the two lines.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}   
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,textfont=it]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{images/peakoffpeak.PDF}%
\caption[Peak reduction in dependency of peak to off-peak price ratio]{Peak reduction in dependency of peak to off-peak price ratio.\\ Source: \citet[p.18]{faruqui2011}}
\label{fig:peaktooffpeak}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm apologizing for any weirdness in my minimal example. I'm a latex beginner and it's the first time I'm asking for help in a forum :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\caption*` for the source to guarantee the same formatting (a possible adjustment of the vertical skip might also be required):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{geometry}   
\usepackage{natbib}   
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,textfont=it]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
\caption{Peak reduction in dependency of peak to off-peak price ratio.}\vskip-\abovecaptionskip
\caption*{Source: \citet[p.18]{faruqui2011}}
\label{fig:peaktooffpeak}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]